# how do I add leading 0's to filenames that have quotation marks around them?

Tags: bash, video, vlc

I downloaded Udacity videos for a course and the file names look like this:

```
'78 - Concurrency Bug Depth Solution.mp4'
'79 - Cuzz Algorithm.mp4'
'7 - Dynamic Program Analysis.mp4'
'80 - Probabilistic Guarantee.mp4'
'81 - Proof of Guarantee (Sketch).mp4'
'82 - Measured vs. Worst-Case Probability.mp4'
'86 - Coverage of Random Testing.mp4'
'88 - Intro to Automated Test Generation.mp4'
'89 - Outline.mp4'
'8 - Static Program Analysis.mp4'
'90 - Korat.mp4'
'91 - The Problem.mp4'
'92 - An Insight.mp4'
'94 - Scheme for Representing Shapes.mp4'
'95 - Representing Shapes.mp4'
'96 - Representing Shapes Solution.mp4'
'97 - A Simple Algorithm.mp4'
'98 - Enumerating Shapes.mp4'
'99 - Enumerating Shapes Solution.mp4'
'9 - Program Invariants.mp4'
'396 - Execution Path of a Program.mp4'
'397 - Computation Tree Example.mp4'
'398 - Existing Approach I.mp4'
'399 - Existing Approach II.mp4'
'39 - Conditions Example.mp4'
'3 - Ariane Rocket Disaster.mp4'
'400 -  Combined Approach.mp4'
'401 - An Illustrative Example .mp4'
'402 - Computation Tree.mp4'
'403 - Computation Tree Solution.mp4'
.
.
.
```

from 1 to 419 I believe.
I saw this: https://walkingrandomly.com/?p=2850
but that gives an error:

```
mv: target '009' is not a directory
```

How can I modify the bash script to rename these files with padded zeros?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the command that results in the error message and the script you use. All variables should be quoted, e.g. `"$foo"` instead of `$foo`. Using a shell function instead of a script might be faster.

Comment: ... also note that if what you have shown is the output of an `ls` command, the filenames may not actually "have quotation marks around them" - see for example [Why is 'ls' suddenly wrapping items with spaces in single quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258679/why-is-ls-suddenly-wrapping-items-with-spaces-in-single-quotes)

Comment: the problem appears to be that shell globbing (`*.mp4`) will not escape the spaces when it passes filenames to the script, so the script sees each piece of the filename separated by a space as a separate filename